# Full Text Search Help

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, search, full-text-search

In a SQL Server database I've two tables: **Job** and **JobKeyword**. Each Job has JobKeywords. I'm trying to learn how to use Full Text Search.

How can I get a list of all jobs in the databases, ordered by shared keywords between the search query and the jobs?

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected results? The way I'm reading your question right now, I'm not sure you even need FTS to accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

From a high level, basically you will need to add full text indexes on the columns you intend to do your searching on.  Then just form the query you would normally use to join the Job and JobKeyword tables together - probably a left inner join.  Once you have that query substitue the correct sql server full text predicate in where your where clause would normally be, and that should be about it.  [Here is a link to Microsoft's explicit implementation instructions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Enjoy!